# Is there any way to comment in or better organize a bower.json file?

Tags: javascript, json, bower

I have a very large project with numerous bower dependencies. In many cases it is unclear whether these dependencies are even still in use within the application or if the version specified was chosen for a reason. Ideally, I would like to be able to put a comment for each dependency to state for which part of the application it is required, so as functionality in the application is removed, we can also remove unnecessary packages from the bower_components. Something like:

```
// videojs plug-in for adding navigable waveforms; used by the video component
"videojs-wavesurfer": "^1.2.2"
```

Unfortunately, json doesn't support commenting, but are there any possible solutions for annotating or better organizing a bower.json file to make it more understandable?

Comment: 1) bower is a dead project. It has not been updated in months. 2) you cannot put comments in a json file. 3) Consider starting to use NPM.

Comment: In addition to what @Neal said, if you want to document your dependencies, you could always add a section to your README file that does just that.

Comment: @Neal Completely wrong.  I don't use bower but it has been updated recently.

Comment: Ha! I was just about to say that @TW80000

Comment: @VtoCorleone it has mainly been README changes...

Comment: @VtoCorleone Bower is not maintained. Most of the changes to [the bower repo](https://github.com/bower/bower) in the last year have been minor documentation issues.

Comment: @Neal - my question wasn't whether you prefer npm or bower :) regardless, of the package manager you're using, I'm just asking if anyone has any better ways to organize or annotate their associated .json files.

Comment: See what @TW80000 said -- use your README or some documentation files for organization.

Comment: @Neal - Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot put comments in a JSON file. JSON is for data and nothing else.

If you would like to document your dependencies, consider adding a section to your README file that contains all of the information relevant to dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

The classic approach to commenting JSON files is to add fake entries, which hopefully will be ignored by the consumer, such as:

```
"video-wavesurfer-comment": 
  "videojs plug-in for adding navigable waveforms; used by the video component"
```

For longer comments, use arrays:

```
"video-wavesurfer-comment": [
  "videojs plug-in for adding navigable waveforms; used by the video component",
  "Remove this for the non-video version."
]
```

Of course, you'll have to put these somewhere where someone won't try to parse them. For instance, they could not go WITHIN `"dependencies":`.